# Eclipse slick2d TiledMap class and paths

Tags: java, slick2d, tiled

I am playing around with slick2d and trying to load a saved tiledmap I have on my computer. I copy the path when I'm creating a new instance but I cant figure out what needs to be done Eclipse keeps saying that it cant find the resource

```
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;



public class MyFirstGame extends BasicGame{

public MyFirstGame()
{
    super("My First Game");
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    try
    {
        AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new MyFirstGame());
        app.setDisplayMode(500, 400, false);
        app.start();
    }
    catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException
    {
    final TiledMap myMap = new TiledMap("C:\Users\dustin\Desktop\firstGameMape.tmx", true);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException
    {
    }

    public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        myMap.render(0.0);
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the error message sent by Eclipse ?

Comment: Try to use a relative path from your game folder like:

"src/main/resources/maps/test.tmx"